# How to call a payable function in ethers, which takes 0 input and payable bnb?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether

I have wrote it like this but it is always throwing error that inputAmount is not in range but it is in range,

const transaction = await preSaleContract.buyTokens({value: inputAmount,
from: userAddress})
await transaction.wait();
and like this also

const transaction = await preSaleContract.buyTokens().send({value: inputAmount,
from: userAddress});

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your input amount.

let tx = await connectedContract.YOUR_PAYABLE_FUNCTION(ALL, OTHER, PARAMETERS, {value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ETH_VALUE_AS_STRING)});

In Your case,

const transaction = await preSaleContract.buyTokens({value: ethers.utils.parseEther(inputAmount), from: userAddress})